# Running Nodejs' Lessc from Cygwin throws error with absolute path

Tags: node.js, django, cygwin, less, django-compressor

I have Windows 10 (64 bits), Cygwin, Nodejs installed via Windows Installer and `lessc` installed on top of Nodejs.

I am trying to make `django-compressor` work with precompilers as suggested in documentation:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    #...
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
    #...
)
```

It throws

`lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\awkwardly\converted\cygwin\path\to\my\file.less'` (Notice the drive letter added)

I tested the command `lessc` from the Cygwin console. It works fine as long as I use relative paths, but when I use an absolute path it converts it to Windows path, even prepending a drive letter, something like

`C:\cygdrive\d\projects\my\path\to\file.less`

How can I fix/workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the option is using `cygpath` to feed `lessc` with an appropriate windows path, like this:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    #...
    ('text/less', 'lessc $(cygpath -w {infile}) > {outfile}'),
    #...
)
```

Also, output must be redirected to `{outfile}` and not passing `{outfile}` as parameter.